# Mark a conversation as read with quick steps in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, conversion

I manage a lot of messages every day and a lot of them are grouped in conversations in Outlook.
Once I read the last of the conversation, I already know the content of the rest of messages in the conversation.
I'd like to make a quick step that affects to the conversation... but I don't want to have to click in the conversation every time. 
There is an option like "send this conversation to X folder"... well I'd like something like "set this conversation as read".
Is there anything like that?
Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the Conversation view and then you could check all related emails in one thread.

Collapse a Conversation and right click it and choose "Mark as Read".

[image]

Comment: Also, keyboard shortcut is CRTL-Q